# Build post from two different layout in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to build a mobile version for my website using Jekyll.
So I want Jekyll to build the same post by using two different layout `post` and `mobile_post`

I've tried, none of these work:

```
   ---
   layout: [post, mobile_post]
   title:  "first post"
   date:   2013-06-12 22:35:00
   categories: Rss
   ---
```

---

```
   ---
   layout: post mobile_post
   title:  "first post"
   date:   2013-06-12 22:35:00
   categories: Rss
   ---
```

Could someone help me out! thanks!!

Comment: What about simply using a responsive layout? Defining multiple layouts is not supported by jekyll (how should that work anyway, your post is available only under *one* link).

Comment: @Polygnome OK then I'll try using responsive as my mobile version, thanks for reply!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin for this exact type of scenario. This should be what you are looking for: https://github.com/saclark/jekyll-multipost